# How to use all hard drives in dedicated server

Tags: dedicated-server

I bought dedicated server and after installing Plesk panel I can see under the server information tab it is showing me the total storage available: 1.7TB. `lsblk` output is:

[image: lsblk output]

But I had bought server with 4TB of storage (2000GBx2) Is there any way to make use of other hard drive or merge them /mount them so that I could use total 4TB memory? How is this achievable?

Comment: You did not do the sane thing and order it with 2 discs in a RAID 1 configuration to start with?

Comment: Typically servers are configured with RAID for reliability and data protection and with only two disks those will be mirrored... That would explain why you only have the capacity of a single 2 TB disk available.

Comment: I have installed centos without raid but still it took 2TB as swap

Comment: here is the screenshot http://imgur.com/qEmiP3k

Comment: Mine servers was unmanaged so I had built it with centos with plesk .thats it . I havent choosen raid or raid 1,2 .. Still I took 2 tb as swap #HBruijn

Comment: That screenshot show two drives with ~1.8T each. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: but i m not able to use 2TB hard drive

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a filesystem in your `sdb1` partition, that is why you cannot use the space.

You can use RAID0 to merge the two devices into one logical device, and then install the OS there. Or you can create a filesystem into `sdb1` and then mount the filesystem into some directory.